# debian: supress find warnings

Tags: debian-lenny

I need to get rid off "access denied" messages which fills my find output.
I've read man find (maybe not too carefully, hit me) and cannot find anything like

-s/--silent or -q/--quiet command line key.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to redirect `find`'s errors with `2>/dev/null', but that may hide some errors you still might want to see, as chris_l mentioned.

If you want a cleaner solution, you can try something like

```
find foo/ \( -type d -and -not -executable -prune \) -o -print
```

which tells `find` not to descend into directories of which it cannot read the contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path -name "foo" 2>&1 | grep -v denied
```

This will get rid of all Permission denied errors. Similarly you may edit the code above depending on the situation

Answer (score 0):

find ... 2>/dev/null

(Note however, that this will redirect all errors, not just "access denied")